# C# WPF - Problem with Material Design Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm new to programming and started to make an application for school. For that I use C# WPF and for a good-looking Application i installed Material Design.

First i started the Demo of Material Design, where you can see what things you can use etc. with the good to copy. So after a quick view I found a nice TextBox with a border and a Checkbox on top of it. The code to copy was this

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBoxEnabledComboBox"
              Margin="32,0,0,8" IsChecked="True">
        Enabled
    </CheckBox>

    <TextBox Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="32,0,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"
             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="This is a text area"
             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBoxEnabledComboBox}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Because I just needed the Textbox, I deleted the Code of the CheckBox and implemented the rest inside my application. So the code now is like this:

```
<TextBox Height="100" Margin="32,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="This is a text area" />
```

The problem now is, that I can't edit the textbox. I guess the TextBox is linked to the CheckBox and because I deleted it, somehow i can't write in it anymore.
It all works fine with a standard textbox, but with the copied code i cant do anything, just see the TextBox with its rounded border.

So can anyone help me, how I can implement the textbox with this border and so on AND while I can edit it? I don't know any solution for that right now, so I would appreciate it, if somebody could help me there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding `IsEnabled="True"` to your textbox? Maybe it's disabled in the styling.

Comment: Already tried that....didn't help at all. :(

Comment: Open blend and edit current style may be there is something in style which is preventing you to edit textbox however i am assuming you removed that IsEnabled binding with checkbox

Comment: yea thats right, I removed the IsEnabled binding with the checkbox, because I dont need a CheckBox in my application. All I need is that TextBox with the border and so on while I can edit it. Actually I have the TextBox with the border but I cant write in my TextBox. I want that to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Try following their [Super Quick Start](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Super-Quick-Start) guide.

Below is a modified version of it that uses a `TextBox`:

- Start new WPF project
- Install *MaterialDesignThemes* nuget: `Install-Package MaterialDesignThemes`
- Edit App.xaml to following:

  ```
  <Application ...>
      <Application.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary>
              <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
              </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          </ResourceDictionary>
      </Application.Resources>
  </Application>
  ```
- Edit MainWindow.xaml to following:

  ```
  <Window
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      ...>
      <StackPanel>
          <TextBox
              materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Hey, that's pretty good!"
              Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}" />
      </StackPanel>
  </Window>
  ```

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work either. As soon as I implement  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}" I cant write in the TextBox anymore. Maybe its useful to know, that I define the TextBoxes inside an UserControl...but I defined the Resources and all that stuff like it was told me in the Starting Guide

Comment: Try following the guide as is. Use the `MainWindow.xaml`. And see it work. After that, put it in a `UserControl`.

Comment: Did exactly that. Edited the App.xaml, the MainWindows.xaml and my Usercontrol.xaml, but I still can't edit it, even when i set the TextBox in the MainWindow. When I set xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" in my .xaml it told me "The namespace "materialDeasign" is unnecessary" ?

Comment: Did you add MaterialDesignThemes nuget package?

Comment: Yea, I just checked it. Installed MaterialDesignThemes and MaterialDesignColor. When I define a normal `<Textbox />` it's also in the MaterialDesign Theme and not like the standard TexBox...I really just have a problem when i add the code `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"` to my TextBox...as soon as I do that, I can't edit it for whatever reason.

Comment: Just created a new WPF-Application project, followed the Starting Guide and tried a TextBox with `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"` on my MainWindow. Can't edit there too (there is also the Message that th namespace is not necessary lol)...so on your project you can edit the Textbox with the Style i mentioned before? I guess its the problem with the link to the checkbox I deleted...man why is thios so hard, just want a TextBox with that nice round border lol

Answer (score 1):

Test this code:

```
Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out you are actually editing the textbox, the **padding** is just hiding your text in the margin.

This worked for me:

```
TextBox c = new TextBox();
c.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
c.Padding = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -10);
c.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

Also, don't set the Height property of the Textbox.

Answer (score -1):

Remove height from xaml code. This would be an issue.